# Perl script or MySQL fix?

Tags: mysql, regex, perl

I am a beginner in Perl and just got a tweak task with a perl scipt. The statement that I am focusing now is:

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT StringValue FROM CustomData WHERE (Record_ID = \'' . $ref->{'Record_ID'} . '\' && Field_ID = \'' . $metadata[11] . '\') LIMIT 1;');
```

The current statement will pull every record that matches the `Record_ID` value. However, it needs to be changed to **only pull records where Record_ID begins with digit 1,2,9**.

I am thinking this is more like a regular expression issue, is that correct? If that is case, I should only be modifying the

```
 Record_ID = \'' . $ref->{'Record_ID'}
```

part. Is that correct? Or that should be something to be fixed in the `prepare` statement?

Comment: It will pull the first matching record because of the "limit 1".

Comment: You should use placeholders instead of trying to interpolate and quote variables yourself. See the DBI documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) instead of trying to interpolate your variables and try to do your own quoting. You might even consider using placeholders for the `'1%'` etc, unless you consider them static throughout all your queries.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( q#
     SELECT StringValue FROM CustomData 
     WHERE (Record_ID = ? && Field_ID = ?) 
     AND (Record_ID LIKE '1%' OR Record_ID LIKE '2%' OR Record_ID LIKE '9%')
     LIMIT 1
#);

$sth->execute($ref->{'Record_ID'}, $metadata[11]);
```

Comment: @TLP- you are using `$dbh->execute`,it needs to be `$sth->execute`. Also your solution gives me error about single quotes `Number found where operator expected at record.pl at line`. Even if I escape the quotes,I get blank output.

Comment: @Devendra Right you are. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `AND`-part in your WHERE clause to filter the unwanted Record_IDs.

```
SELECT StringValue 
FROM CustomData \
WHERE (Record_ID = \'' . $ref->{'Record_ID'} . '\' && Field_ID = \'' . $metadata[11] . '\') 
AND (Record_ID  LIKE "1%" OR Record_ID  LIKE "2%" OR Record_ID  LIKE "9%")
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid masking the `'` so many times you can use `qq`

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare( qq§SELECT StringValue FROM CustomData 
                            WHERE (Record_ID = '$ref->{Record_ID}' AND 
                                   Field_ID = '$metadata[11]') LIMIT 1§
                       ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right about changing the part `Record_ID = \'' . $ref->{'Record_ID'} . '\'`

replace it with `Record_ID LIKE \'1%\' || Record_ID LIKE \'2%\' || Record_ID LIKE \'9%\'`

Remove `LIMIT 1`,this only matches any one row,either of starting with 1,2 or 9

Here's how I think solution could go

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT StringValue 
    FROM CustomData 
    WHERE ( Record_ID LIKE \'1%\' || Record_ID LIKE \'2%\' || Record_ID LIKE \'9%\' 
    && Field_ID = \''. $metadata . '\');');

$sth->execute;

while (my @arr=$sth->fetchrow_array())
   {
   print @arr;
   }
```